# how to match all the nodes that have a key in lookup table in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

Given the input XML file:

```
        <acctInfo>
                <wfInfo>
                    <aaa>1</aaa>
                    <bbb>1</bbb>
                    <ccc>1</ccc>
                    <ddd>1</ddd>
                    <eee>1</eee>
                </wfInfo>
            <acctInfo>
```

And the lookup file:

```
<fields>
    <field>
       <name>aaa</name>
       <Updatekey>aaakey</Updatekey>
    </field>

    <field>
       <name>bbb</name>
       <Updatekey>bbbkey</Updatekey>
    </field>

    <field>
       <name>ccc</name>
       <Updatekey>ccckey</Updatekey>
    </field>
</fields>
```

I would like to use XSLT/XPATH to count all the nodes in the input xml file that have corresponding key in the lookup table. in the above example, count should give 3. Thanks.

Comment: @Erica: Your statement is not generally true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "count(/*/*/*
             [name()
             =
              document('file:///c:/temp/delete/lookup.xml')/*/*/name]
            )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<acctInfo>
    <wfInfo>
        <aaa>1</aaa>
        <bbb>1</bbb>
        <ccc>1</ccc>
        <ddd>1</ddd>
        <eee>1</eee>
    </wfInfo>
</acctInfo>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
3
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I can't seem to find the xslt part (This transformation:), could you please check and post?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the **document** command to reference another xml document in your XSLT.

```
<xsl:value-of 
   select="count(//wfInfo/*[document('Lookup.xml')//field/name = local-name()])" />
```

i.e. Match all elements under **wfInfo** where there is a field name in the lookup.xml with the same name as the element.

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
   <xsl:template match="/"> 
      <xsl:value-of 
         select="count(//wfInfo/*[document('Lookup.xml')//field/name = local-name()])" />
   </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is **3**

Comment: TimC: A minor problem with this answer is that it is counting not what the OP wants. The op needs "*count all the nodes in the input xml file that have corresponding key in the lookup table*". This is generally different from the count of all the nodes in the lookup file that match nodes in the source XML document.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, that gives me the right direction. I'd been thinking about switching context nodes with xsl:for-each and xsl:apply-templates.

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach:

```
            ┌─────────┐
            │Meta XSLT│
┌──────────┐└────┬────┘┌──────────┐
│Lookup XML├─────┴────>┤Inner XSLT│
└──────────┘┌─────────┐└────┬─────┘┌──────────┐
            │Input XML├─────┴─────>┤  Output  │
            └─────────┘            └──────────┘
```

Use a `Meta XSLT` which takes `Lookup XML` as input, generate an `Intermedia XSLT` to process the output